# How to download image from URL in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have an image URL like this:

`http://phpimagick.com/customImage/Imagick/distortImage?imagePath=Lorikeet&distortion=1`

I want to download this image to my public folder in Laravel, and then fetch the image from my public file and use in my project.

The same code work for this URL:

`https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCveg.jpg`

(The image in this URL is a JPG).

My code:

```
if ($request->city_image_hidden_link) {                           
   $image_to_upload = $request->city_image_hidden_link;
   $extra_name = rand(1, 50000) + time();

   $filename = basename($image_to_upload);

   file_put_contents('assets/UploadedImages/' .$extra_name .   $filename,file_get_contents($image_to_upload)); 
   $target_dir = "assets/UploadedImages/";
   $image_to_upload = "/" . $target_dir . $extra_name.$filename;
   $data['city_image'] = $image_to_upload;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't assume the extension from the filename but from the mimetype

```
$imageDownloaded = file_get_contents($image_to_upload);
$imageType = exif_imagetype($imageDownloaded);
$mimeType = explode('/', image_type_to_mime_type($imageType));
$extension = $mimeType[1];
```

Of course you can improve the logic there, also check for existence or falsey returns skipped for brevity